# How to fill a datepicker with value from database in VB 6.0?

Tags: vb6

I am working in VB6.0. I have this datepicker  and I also have a datagridview. I am trying to make that when I click a column data enter in the textboxes and so with the datepicker to get the value of the date from the database

This is my code:

```
txtData.Value = dtmhs.Columns(3)
```

But I get the following error, any idea how to do it?

**On database i declared the date as varchar because it had some problems with the date format yyyy/mm/dd and not dd/mm/yyy**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using varchar for your date columns will ultimately make your formatting issues worse, not better. I guarantee it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn any idea how to fill the datepicker with values from database or it must be date?

Comment: Your question does not actually include the error details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JoelCoehoorn pointed out: you're better off with storing dates in a date variable/column, both in your code and your database. It's *very* easy to achieve the desired formatting of a date using the [`Format$()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function, i.e. create a `String` from a date with the formatting of your liking. The opposite however is prone to lots and lots of errors.

```
Dim sMyDateAsString As String
sMyDateAsString = Format$(dtmMyDateAsDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

As for setting the value of a DateTimePicker, again - with a date *variable* it's as simple as `dtpMyDateTime.Value = dtmMyDateVariable`.

If you absolutely *have* to use any other variable type, IMHO the best approach is to set the individual date/time properties of the control, e.g.

```
With dtpMyDateTime
   .Year = 2021
   .Month = 12
   .Day = 09
   ' Also set the time part, if needed...
   .Hour = 23
   .Minute = 58
   .Second = 0
   ' ... and now cue Iron Maiden's "Two minutes to midnight" ;-)
End With
```

Keep in mind, that these properties expect *numeric* values, so if you store your date in a 'String` variable, you have to convert those first. See, all that hassle with storing dates in strings...